# Digital Persona Verifying process take a lot of time with huge database

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I'm developing a software that is using the Digital Persona U.are.U 4000b fingerprint reader.

It's working OK. But I'm getting performance problems during fingerprint verification.

My database has around 3.000 fingerprints registered there and I need to LOOP all of them during the verify process.

But every successful fingerprint reading take around 7 seconds to match the respective record of my database (it depends on its index).

It's not an acceptable scenario for me, because I need to register (and show their data, photo ... in real-time) at least 400 students in an interval of 20 minutes.
The problem is really the huge fingerprints database, because when I tested it with a smaller one, it worked fine.

I'm using .NET with C# and a Free SDK for the fingerprints.
The line of code that is causing this trouble is that one, which is executed into a FOREACH (for each registered fingerprint of the database):

```
verificator.Verify(features, template, ref result);
```

- `verificator` is a `DPFP.Verification.Verification` object which treats the verification process;
- `features` is a `DPFP.FeatureSet` object which contains the data of the actual fingerprint;
- `template` is a `DPFP.Template` object which represents each of the registered fingerprints;
- `result` is a `DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result` object which contains the return of each fingerprint validation.

Here is the whole `process` method:

```
    protected void process(DPFP.Sample sample)
    {
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);
        bool verified = false;
        if (features != null)
        {
            DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();
            //"allTemplates" is an List<> of objects that contains all the templates previously loaded from DB
            //There is no DB access in these lines of code
            foreach (var at in allTemplates)
            {
                verificator.Verify(features, at.template, ref result);
                if (result.Verified)
                {
                    register(at.idStudent);
                    verified = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!verified)
            error("Invalid student.");
    }
```

Am I doing it correctly?

There is another way of doing that work?

Comment: I would profile the database to see if you can identify what query is causing the slowness.  Once identified you can start looking at how to potentially improve performance.

Comment: The problem is certainly not related to the database. I perform a preloading of registered fingerprints. The shown line is the cause of the slowness.

Comment: How do you know the shown line isn't hitting the DB?

Comment: If it's not hitting the DB and you don't have access to the source for the Verify function I don't think there is much you can do

Comment: Hi. I've added the whole "process" method in the body of the question.

Comment: That doesn't really help.  I need to see the `Verify` function.

Comment: `verificator` is a `DPFP.Verification.Verification`. It's an SDK's class.

Comment: Guy. I just want to know if anybody here know if I'm writing my code in a right way and how I can improve it, because I do not have access to the classes of SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by purchasing (I "won" it, because I had already bought a reader) the new version of the SDK, that already implements the **identify** (1:n) function.
You can get more information and download (purchase) the SDK at [their website](http://devportal.digitalpersona.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try out SourceAFIS. It's open source and if you cache the fingerprints in memory it performs the sort of 1-N identify processes you're talking about at faster than 10k fingerprints /second. The source is also 100% C#.

Answer (score 0):

is better to convert the template to string

```
byte [] a = new byte [1632];
Template.Serialize (ref a);
string Convert.ToBase64String basestring = (a);
```

and then return to normal the template

```
byte [] b = new byte [1632];
b = Convert.FromBase64String (trace) / / pass the base-64 string to a byte array.
/ / create a Template type varibale where we store the template
DPFP.Template DPFP.Template template = new ();
/ / what to compare it desserializamos
template.DeSerialize (b);
```